# Importing Delicious export into Firefox 3

Tags: firefox, delicious

The HTML export file from Delicious creates an HTML file that, while importable into Firefox, loses all of the tags, which pretty much misses the point of delicious.

Every link I've found to do the import doesn't work:

1. The online converter [Delicious-to-Firefox 3](http://delicious-to-firefox3.heroku.com/) keeps throwing a server error; the ["better" version](http://delicious.e-accent.com/) is down
2. I tried using the [trick of syncing Delicious bookmarks to Flock](http://www.blogsdna.com/342/importing-delicious-bookmarks-to-firefox-3.htm) and then restoring that file to my Firefox browser. Although the bookmarks are in Firefox, they don't show up anywhere. I know they're in Firefox because when I create a backup file, they're in the JSON file but they refuse to show in the browser anywhere (clicking on any tag shows an empty list)

Basically, I'm looking for someone who has successfully imported their delicious bookmarks, with tags, into Firefox 3.6.13 (Mac).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another online converter -- http://xdlcs.com

It generates a JSON file for Firefox that includes both your tags and descriptions. Drop me a line (there's a mailto link at the bottom of the page) if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: The website look down for me

Answer (score 1):

One solution is using the [Flock 2](http://flock.com/) browser:

Sign-in to the Del.icio.us social account in the Flock browser, let Flock synchronize bookmarks (may take a few hours) with its built-in bookmarks, do an export of the .json file and then import that into Firefox 3.

See this article: [Use Flock 2.0 to Import Delicious Bookmarks & Tags Into Firefox 3.0](http://www.fansoftech.com/2008/06/16/use-flock-20-to-import-delicious-bookmarks-tags-into-firefox-30/).

A second possibility is to use web interface found in [Del.icio.us to Firefox 3 bookmark](http://delicious-to-firefox3.heroku.com/), although I have no way of testing it.

If this doesn't work, it is also [said](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=659182&start=15) that if you export .json from flock and export html from the del.icio.us website and then import both into firefox (.json first), then you’ll have tags and bookmarks.

Comment: Please see part 2 of my question.

Comment: Right. So I added a part 2 to my answer.

Comment: Part 2 of your answer is #1 in my question. Was that on purpose? :)

Comment: The purpose was to find a way of making it work for you ...

Comment: I know, but you do get how it's kind of funny that the two options you listed were the ones I tried and didn't work. I will look into the possible solution of .json + .html import if xdlcs.com doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

http://xdlcs.com did the trick for me. If I had the reputation to be able to comment on user59642's answer, I would. I'd also up vote him.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has two bugs with attached patch:

Export with tags https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=423197

Import with tags https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416611

Comment: Yes, but how do you use this in Firefox Quantum?